# error programing atmega32 lock bits

Tags: atmega, avrdude

I am trying to use lock bits for protection on atmega32.I am not being able to write lock bits to it its giving me verification error while doing it.Can you tell me correct way to do this?

This is the error I am getting while programing:
[image]

Comment: Do you use a decoupling capacitor? (100nF will do). Also, do you have a RESET pullup resistor? (10K)

Comment: is it related to lock bits ?

Comment: It is related to programming process, and what you do here is programming fusebits, isn't it?

Comment: Also, after programming, check if they are in your desired state: avrdude -p atmega32 -c stk500v2 -P disabled  -U lock:r:"tmp_fuse_lock.hex":i

Comment: what do I do about writing those lock bits is my question?

Answer (score -1):

http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece473/lectures/fuses.pdf
check out this pdf. You Will find your answer.

avrdude> w efuse 0 0xff
//write extended fuse
//write extended fuse

> > > w efuse 0 0xff 
> > >       avrdude> w hfuse 0 0x89
> > >       //wire high fuse
> > >       //wire high fuse
> > >       w hfuse 0 0x89

avrdude> w lfuse 0 0x2f
//write low fuse
//write low fuse

> > > w lfuse 0 0x2f

Double check 0XFC is correct value or not?

Comment: A proper answer should not require anyone to leave the site.

Comment: i don't understand.What are you saying?

Comment: You edited 1 minute after my comment, so it's fixed, I guess.